# MVC WebApi Routing No HTTP resource was found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

this is my first time using MVC and I have been stuck trying to get the webApi routing to work.

I have a simple controller which looks like this

```
namespace XRM.Controllers
{
    public class PipelinesWebApiController : ApiController
    {
        static List<XRM.Models.XRM_PipelineStages> stages = new List<Models.XRM_PipelineStages>
        {
            new Models.XRM_PipelineStages() { stageName = "test" },
            new Models.XRM_PipelineStages() { stageName = "test2" },
            new Models.XRM_PipelineStages() { stageName = "test3" }
        };

        public IEnumerable<XRM.Models.XRM_PipelineStages> Get()
        {
            return stages;
        }

        public XRM_PipelineStages Get(int id)
        {
            return stages.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ROWUID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
namespace XRM {

    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
namespace XRM {

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            DevExtremeBundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

    }
}
```

And whenever I try to access using

```
http://localhost:58061/api/PipelinesWebApi
```

I get the error message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58061/api/PipelinesWebApi'.

I have checked that I have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in my *WebApiConfig.cs* too.

I really don't know why I can't seem to reach it.

Comment: I have tried your code but not able to reproduce this issue. At my side it's working fine.

Comment: @ReyanChougle are you using MVC5?

Comment: Yes. It is MVC5

Comment: @BloopieBloops What is currently shown should work. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked fine at my end. I am not able to reproduce this issue. Anyway, you can try one more way of routing as shown below:

Change the `routeTemplate` as `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` in `WebApiConfig.cs` and call the URL along with action name like `api/PipelinesWebApi/Get`

Comment: I would recommend to create a fresh new project and try again.

Comment: Hi, I have added Global.asax

Comment: I guess I have to use another method for my task that do not requires WebApi

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I recreated the project